# Jenkins agent SSL Handshake failure

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-agent

My Jenkins controller is running on an Ubuntu VM. Jenkins was installed via apt and the SSL termination takes place on nginx, on the same server.

When I try to connect agents, it does not work. The agents, at least on VM level, report an SSL error.

The agents in Kubernetes terminate immediately and I have no access to the logs.

How can I solve the problem with the SSL?
My certificate is an official, purchased certificate.

```
var/lib/jenkins# java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://jenkins.example.com/computer/jr1/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -workDir "/var/lib/jenkins"
Apr 12, 2022 6:43:59 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /var/lib/jenkins/remoting as a remoting work directory
Apr 12, 2022 6:43:59 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /var/lib/jenkins/remoting
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1392)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1300)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:508)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:346)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:297)
```